# Do a simple calculation in a mustache.js template

Tags: javascript, template-engine, mustache

Is it possible to do calculations in mustache.js templates?

I want to multiple a value called `ratio` by a fixed amount e.g. 240

My tag looks like this:

```
<div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.myapp.demo/{{url}}" class="item" style="height:{{ratio * 240}}"></div>
```

Since the `url` value is displayed correctly, I feel it must be the calculation that is causing me trouble.

Comment: Why not do the calculation before that value is passed to the template? Can you please show us the code that you're using to render the template?

Comment: are you sure its not the fact that you're forgetting the "px"

Comment: Yes I can do the calculation before passing it to the template, but the amount of work to do that is a lot more, so I wanted to avoid it.That's they way I'm doing it now.

Comment: You might have missed the bit where the question starts with "Is it possible ...". It's understandable, seeing as how I only mention in it in the first three words.

Answer (score 11):

### Option 1

You can do this using a function:

template:

```
<div>
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.myapp.demo/{{url}}" 
       class="item" style="height:{{#ratio}} {{x240Times}} {{/ratio}}">
</div>
```

code:

```
Mustache.render(template,{
 ratio: 2,
 x240Times: function() {
    return this.ratio * 240;
  }
});
```

### Option 2

You could also use my extension [mustache-wax](http://jvitela.github.io/mustache-wax/) to use formatters in your templates, for example:

Define a "multiply" formatter which accepts one argument:

```
Mustache.Formatters = {
    "multiply": function (value, multiplier) {
        return value * multiplier;
    }
}
```

Use it in your template:

```
<div>
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.myapp.demo/{{url}}" 
       class="item" style="height:{{ratio | multiply:240}}">
</div>
```